# What is the diference between gfloat and float?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm a beginner with **Gtk** and i'm learning a lot throught [gtk docs](https://docs.gtk.org).

I cannot understand why there are so many alternative types like

- gfloat vc float
- gint vs int
- gchar vs char
- gboolean
- ...

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/?q=gfloat

https://docs.gtk.org/glib/?q=gfloat

On docs there is nothing about why so many alternative types and which one I should use on my **gtk apps**.

I just found this definition of types https://libsoup.org/glib/glib-Basic-Types.html

Comment: On your linked page: "*Basic Types — standard GLib types, defined for ease-of-use and portability*" - you should be using these. They are defined in such a way that you should not worry about the underlying implementation, such that your *gtk* code will be portable across machines where `int` or `float` or others could be of different sizes or representations.

Comment: gtyples.h: `typedef float   gfloat;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. `gint` is described as *"Corresponds to the standard C int type."* I don't think that helps the portability at all.

Comment: Looking at the list of basic types, I am not convinced. Apart from `gssize`, all other types are already covered by C99. Since everybody should really use at least C99 nowadays anyway, portability is not really an issue. Claimed "ease-of-use" is also debatable. I think using these types will only make reuse of code with non-gtk projects harder.